# Не отображаются буквы дисков в JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing

В чем может быть проблема?

[image]

Код:

```
    fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new JQSFileFilter());
    fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    JQSFileView fv=new JQSFileView();
    fc.setFileView(fv);
```

Вью:

```
    public class JQSFileView extends FileView{
    @Override
    public String getName(File file){
        return FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file.getName());
    }
    }
```

Фильтр:

```
    public class JQSFileFilter extends FileFilter {

       private final String EXTENSION="jqs";

       public boolean accept(File f) {
          if (f.isDirectory()) {
            return true;
          }

          String extension = getExtension(f);
          if (extension != null) {
           if (extension.equals(EXTENSION)) {
            return true;
           } else {
            return false;
           }
          }

         return false;
       }


       public static String getExtension(File f) {
        String ext = null;
        String s = f.getName();
        int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

        if (i > 0 && i < s.length() - 1) {
         ext = s.substring(i + 1).toLowerCase();
         }
         return ext;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
          return "Файлы обучающей системы";
        }

        public String getExt(){
         return EXTENSION;
        }
  }
```

При удалении вьюхи всё работает, правда, я так и не понял, как она отрицательно влияет

Comment: Названия дисков русские?

Comment: @Gorets, нет английские, и, как видите, даже буквы не отображаются, которые в любом случае английские (C,D,E...)

Comment: проблема может быть в коде который вызывает этот диалог, зря вы его не добавили

Comment: @jmu, сделал

Comment: В принцыпе я знал что проблема не в самом file chooser, т.к. его поведение предсказуемое (я предполагаю что он работает правильно). В вашем случае проблема в JQSFileFilter или JQSFileView. Если не найдете в них ошибку, выкладывайте их код тоже, разберемся

Comment: можно проблема и в самой ОС, какая она? какието там стили стоят? и тд?

Comment: @jmu, добавил

Comment: @Gorets, Windows XP без дополнительный стилей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменил вьюху и все встало на свои места:

```
public class JQSFileView extends FileView{
@Override
public String getName(File file){

    String fileName = null;
    if(file != null) {
        if (file.isFile()){
            fileName =FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file.getName());
        } else {

        fileName = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemDisplayName(file);
        }
    }

    return fileName;
}
}
```

Comment: у меня получилось практически тоже самое:

    public class JQSFileView extends FileView
    {
        @Override
        public String getName ( File file )
        {
            String name = file.getName () ;
            if ( file.isFile () && name.endsWith ( ".jqs" ) )
            {
                return name.substring ( 0, name.length () - 4 ) ;
            }
    
            return super.getName ( file ) ;
        }
    }